# Run time error in timer function in Android Application?

Tags: android, timer, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get the GPS location for every Half hour using BroadCastReceiver. But I got following error.

**Error message**

```
01-09 17:24:44.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().
```

my code

```
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
     public void run() {
      result();//here i cal the Gps function
        }
     };
     mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask,1000,50000);
```

My Method result() is not getting called.

Comment: Like I said in your previous post, this question has been asked and answered on this website multiple times before. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare

Comment: Does result() do any changes to any Views?

Comment: no jusi i got latitude value here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Handler in **run() method**.in Handler handle **result();** method.